# Swapping the order of multiselct drop down option like gmail compose recepient option

Tags: jquery, swap, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

i am using http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ to provide multiselect feature in the application (scenario:for every book there can n number of authors )

which are selected using drop down which is working fine ,but know user should be provide with the ability to swap the options in multi select box like the one in gmail compose recipient option

Is there a option which i can enable to do this in the plugin

Or else please suggest me how to go about it

(author1,author2,author3) when the user press control and drag the option in the select box it should change the order of the author

Comment: asmSelect seems to be doing but can someone please say does it support for angularjs application source:https://code.google.com/p/jquery-asmselect/